# Is there a trick to close a specific tab in firefox the other way around?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Sometimes we open a page with evil script so that we can't click the cross icon to close.

Is there a trick to close it ?

Comment: In a comment below, you mention a particular problem of closing a tab that's displaying an infinite loop of Javascript alert boxes. Although I didn't find a solution for Firefox 3.0 or Internet Explorer 7, I discovered both Google Chrome 4.0 and Opera 10.01 provide a check box on the alert box itself to help you escape.

Answer (score 4):

You can press [ctrl] + [w] button at the same time to close the current tab.

Much like [mouse wheel] click on the tab

Comment: No,it won't work when there is always an `alert` box..

Answer (score 3):

If you visit pages with potential evil scripts you should use the extension [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/722) to prevent them to run

To close a tab, similarly to middle click or Ctrl+W, you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try middle clicking the tab to close it. Middle click and clicking with the scroll wheel are the same on most mouses.

Comment: But only if you haven't overridden the default behaviour ;)

Comment: @ChrisF - But why would you?!! That feature is *awesome*!!! :)

Comment: in the past I've overridden the middle click at the OS level to perform a double click to see if it helped my (admittedly self diagnosed) RSI. Several reinstalls/rebuilds later and I haven't done that, partly because I now use the mouse left handed and have a better mouse.

Comment: @ChrisF - Well that's a good reason. I wasn't thinking at the OS level, I was thinking about modding the mid-click behavior for FF only.